# How would I implement a Queue of type Dictionary<int, string> and iterate/enqueue/dequeue in C#

Tags: c#, types, dictionary, queue

I am looking to implement a `Queue` of type `Dictionary<int, string>` and be able to iterate/enqueue/dequeue.

What's ultimately needed is a `queue` of `int`, `string`, whatever guise it takes.

So far I have something like:

```
  private static Queue<Dictionary<int, string>> requestQueue = new Queue<Dictionary<int, string>>();

  foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> dictionaryListItem in dictionaryList)
  {
      requestQueue.Enqueue( dictionaryListItem ); // error
  }
```

but can't seem to enqueue with the above. Would anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The syntax is easy, but the code doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are trying to enqueue a different type. `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is not the same as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @jon I am trying to simply have a queue of int, string

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime: Then you should write `Queue<Tuple<int, string>>` or `Queue<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you have a queue of dictionaries, but try to add a single dictionary value to your queue.

If you indeed want to have a queue of dictionaries, you should change your code like this:

```
requestQueue.Enqueue(dictionaryList);
```

If you actually want a queue of key value pairs, change your queue to this:

```
Queue<KeyValuePair<int, string>> requestQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple snippet:

```
Queue<KeyValuePair<int, string>> queue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
void Enqueue()
{
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "One"));
    queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Two"));
    //..
}
void Dequeue()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var kvp = queue.Dequeue();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("key: {0}, value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
    }
    //..
}
```